# Replacing CMOS battery affect to the RAID controller?

Tags: raid-0

Recently I replaced my graphic card and the BIOS does post with FF status code but in the step of Verify DMI Pool Data hangs. I'm thinking remove de CMOS battery for reset de board but I have a RAID 0 configured with the Intel Raid Controller include in the mother board (GA-X58A-UD5) and I am not sure if RAID 0 will be lost or not.

Comment: I would contact gigabyte support and ask, only they would know for sure. Use the Contact button near the bottom of this page>>>>>https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Support

Comment: If the system has been properly configured, removing the CMOS battery (say, to replace it) will not harm or reset the configuration.

Comment: CMOS would reset the motherboard's firmware to default, which has nothing to do with the RAID controller _(Intel RST is software, not hardware, RAID - if this was dealing with hardware RAID, at worst you'd have to boot to the hardware RAID's option ROM, but even that's unlikely)_